# Update/Insert cache entries during doctrine entity save

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

There are tons of documentation regarding how to use result cache in Doctrine. However, I was not able to find single documentation regarding how to update/insert the cache during entity save in doctrine. 
Currently for update I am using.

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$cacheDriver = $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl();

$cacheDriver->delete($key);

$searchEntity->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime())
             ->setData([]);

$entityManager->persist($searchEntity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

and for insert something like

```
$searchEntity = new Entity;
$entityManager->persist($searchEntity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

However in both cases I would like to refresh/insert the cache. Is there any way to achieve this nice and easy way without manually creating/updating cache entries.

Answer (score 0):

Created a [social network](https://campus-discounts.com) using Symfony Standard Edition which includes Doctrine. I have encountered this problem when I felt like it was a waste to keep deleting the cache and querying the DB a after an insert/update yet the data to insert/update is readily available.

I agree totally, that there is no clear documentation for this. In my many weeks research, there is no option but to manually build the cache upon DB insert, it is an array of arrays i.e multidimensional array. I had to query the DB and create a cache entry, assign it a value, pass it to twig and do a var dump on my dev environment to see how it looks and mimic its structure upon a successful insert (you can create a listener for this). Since my social network is about discounts, every time one is liked I update the cache by searching through this array for a matching id key and then updating its total likes count by adding (or subtracting 1) same applies to total comments and shares, etc. I have successfully tested this when I started out using Apc cache, then Memcached and now my current cache is redis and its still working.

Please refer to my older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365870/update-doctrine-cache-values-in-symfony) for some sample code